# Excel can not stop using text to column

Tags: microsoft-excel

After I use the *text to column* functionality in excel, I cannot stop it. I noticed this error in Excel 2003 and up.

Imagine I copy some large text, paste it into a sheet, and run *text to column*, to separate it at every `space`.
I keep working, and now I want to paste a different text for a different reason. I do not want it separated by every space, but it still is. So far I only found two solutions:

1. Closing excel completely (every workbook, not just the misbehaving one) and reopening the workbook
2. Pasting the content into a table in a Word document, and copy-pasting this table to excel

Both are overly complicated, is there a better way to stop *text to column*?

This is not about the [import wizard](https://superuser.com/questions/586677/prevent-excel-from-converting-text-to-columns).

Comment: Do you have any **Event** macros in your workbook ??

Comment: To clarify - you copy text into Excel, run text to columns to split it on spaces; you then copy another piece of text, and as soon as you paste it in it splits by spaces without you doing anything?

Comment: no macros, and this happens exactly

Answer (score 2):

No you are correct. This is feature. It presumes that once you've designated how you want to convert the copied text all future texts will be copied using the same conversions.

I think you can stop it, if you run another Text to Columns function on dummy data and remove any columns