# How to stop Text-to-Columns splits as default

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting, microsoft-excel-365

I was copy-pasting some data from a PDF price book into Excel. I then then split the data into different columns along the `$`. However, when I then copy-pasted the next section of the PDF into Excel, it automatically split along the `$`. The problem is, I don't want this data to be split along that now.

How can I reset that so that Excel does not automatically recognize `$` as a delimiter for all incoming data?

Comment: Excel sets the last format as the default.  You will need to reset it manually by doing something like: https://superuser.com/questions/586677/prevent-excel-from-converting-text-to-columns in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text To Columns remembers your last parse settings but you can only run it on a nonempty range. Follow these steps to reset the parse settings:

1. Enter `foo` into an unused cell, say `Z1`
2. With `Z1` selected, click `Text To Columns` from the `Data` ribbon and choose `Delimited`
3. Uncheck each delimiter and click `Finish`

Your next paste won't automatically parse. Instead, you can choose `Text To Columns` and choose your own parse settings.

Comment: This works. It would be nice if there were a setting to tell Excel to not remember the Text to Columns settings, but this is better than nothing.